# Mysql prefix a column name in Select statement

Tags: mysql

I may not be getting my terms correctly hence couldn't find a answer on the web.

I have 2 tables like this

```
customer_db - Customer Data
CustomerID    CustomerName     CustomerContact
1             John             1234
2             Anna             5678
3             Angel            2468

customer_channel - Chat Channel Name
ChannelName            OnlineStatus
private-customer-1     YES
private-customer-2     NO
```

So normally I would do something like this

```
Select a.OnlineStatus, b.CustomerName, b.CustomerContact FROM customer_db a,
customer_channel b WHERE a.CustomerID = b.ChannelName
```

Where the "private-customer-" prefix is there so I cannot do the match.

I've tried to add a prefix but it doesn't work. **How can I SELECT a table adding a 'text prefix' to column name in the WHERE statement?**

```
Select a.OnlineStatus, b.CustomerName, b.CustomerContact FROM customer_db a,
customer_channel b WHERE a.CustomerID = 'private-customer-'+b.ChannelName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function, a comma(,) is an old way, try to use `join`:

```
SELECT
    a.OnlineStatus,
    b.CustomerName,
    b.CustomerContact
FROM customer_db a
JOIN customer_channel b
ON a.CustomerID = concat('private-customer-', b.ChannelName)
```

Answer (score 0):

> adding a 'text prefix' to column name in the WHERE statement

NO, you can't do that unless you are making it a dynamic query (prepared statement). Prefixing or suffixing is allowed only for column or table name alias.

(OR) you can use a subquery and do the `JOIN` with that subquery result like

```
Select a.OnlineStatus, 
b.CustomerName,
 b.CustomerContact 
FROM customer_db a JOIN ( select CustomerName, CustomerContact,
'private-customer-'+ ChannelName as channelName
from customer_channel ) b 
ON a.CustomerID = b.channelName;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Using Concat function..

```
  Select a.OnlineStatus,
         b.CustomerName, 
         b.CustomerContact 
  FROM customer_db a,
       customer_channel b 
  WHERE a.CustomerID = concat('private-customer-', b.ChannelName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using replace or substring
for example given

```
drop table if exists a;
create table a(CustomerID  int,   CustomerName  varchar(5),   CustomerContact int);
insert into a values
(1,             'John' ,            1234),
(2,             'Anna' ,            5678),
(3,             'Angel',            2468);

drop table if exists b;
create table b (ChannelName varchar(20),            OnlineStatus  varchar(3));
insert into b values
('private-customer-1' ,    'YES'),
('private-customer-2' ,    'NO');

Select b.OnlineStatus, a.CustomerName, a.CustomerContact 
FROM   a
join  b on  a.CustomerID = replace(b.ChannelName,'private-customer-','');

Select b.OnlineStatus, a.CustomerName, a.CustomerContact 
FROM   a
join  b on  a.CustomerID = substring(b.ChannelName,18,length(b.channelname) -17)
```

Both queries result in

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| OnlineStatus | CustomerName | CustomerContact |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
| YES          | John         |            1234 |
| NO           | Anna         |            5678 |
+--------------+--------------+-----------------+
```